# Write a check to avoid error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python

For a Python script, I need to write a check before I enter in a loop:

```
for fact_entry in range(len(facts['items'][0]['facts'])):
    [...]
```

I obtain this error:

```
    [...]
    for fact_entry in range(len(facts['items'][0]['facts'])):
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I add some print commands, I see that I receive this error when 'facts' contains this value:

```
{'items': [], 'totalCount': 0, 'partialResults': False, 'metadata': {'processingTime': 2}
```

So, how can I check that to skip the loop?

Comment: `len(facts['items']) > 0` (or, given that empty collections are [false-y](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), just `facts['items']`)? Alternatively you can use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to provide a plausible default that allows the expression to result in an empty list even if `facts['items']` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put you for loop under this if condition

```
if len(facts['items'])>0:
   for fact_entry in range(len(facts['items'][0]['facts'])):
```

As a side note, fact_enty will be an index as range return iteratable of numbers, you can get fact_entry by

```
for fact_entry in facts['items'][0]['facts']:
  ....
```

Comment: Just `if facts['items']:` would do as well.